# In Objective-C, what does a comma do when used as a statement separator?

Tags: objective-c

I am looking though some source code from a third party and am repeatedly seeing a syntax that is new to me. Basically they are separating statements with commas instead of semicolons. It compiles and works, but I don't understand what it is doing. It looks like so

```
if(url)[url release], url = nil;
```

and they also use it without the if sometimes

```
[url release], url = nil;
```

What's going on here?

Comment: This is not useful in this situation and just makes it harder to read. Where it might be useful is if some assignment had to happen to two variables with a release, like: var1 = [var2 release], var2 = nil; but even in this case, a block would make it much cleaner, much easier to read and much easier to debug.

Comment: Agreed about the unclarity of the first example, but the second is not so bad in a dealloc implementation, although a semicolon instead of a comma would do much the same thing.  I find it easier to read for a long list of releases, because you don't have alternating lines doing two different things.  Semantically, releasing an object and setting it to nil are like a single operation (or should be if you want to avoid zombies).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As in C and C++, the comma operator computes the thing on its left side and then computes the thing on the right; the overall value of the expression is the value of the right side. Basically, this lets a single expression do two things (the one on the left side being presumably for side effects such as a method call or assignment). Yes, the syntax is somewhat ambiguous with that used in function calls and variable declarations.

I prefer to use an honest block containing multiple statements where possible. Longer, but ultimately cleaner. Easier to debug too.

Comment: I totally agree with Donal, especially for this kind of thing. Not using a block here is just lazy and harder to read.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be sure to avoid using it for this purpose in my own code. I'm glad I know you can do this now though. Might be useful elsewhere.

Comment: Totally agree with Donal on using multiple statements rather than this syntax.

Answer (score 3):

These are comma separated expressions and are evaluated from left to right, with the result of the entire expression being the last expression evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of ***my favorite*** "features" of C, ObjC, etc…

Understanding this operator unlocks all sorts of possibilities for *jQuery-like.chain-able.commands*, and a more concise (*thoug-some-would-argue-less-readable*) expression of MANY common idioms.. For example...

```
-(id)init { 
     return self != super.init ? nil : [self setProperty:@"EPIC"], 
     NSLog(@"One line inits are: %@.", _property), self;        }
```

> *LOG ➜* `One line inits are: EPIC.`

Comment: I'd slap someone in a code review for this. I personally find it very hard to read and unnecessary. But that is just my opinion.

Comment: I'm a notorious target for many such "slap attacks"... but alas, many have tried, and most have failed - to slap the "like" out of me - over things "like this", sigh.

Comment: For the sake of clarity and simplicity I would advise to avoid writing such an init method.